# Setting attribute disabled on a SPAN element does not prevent click events

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a `<span>` element which does something on a click event.

When I disable it, using jQuery:

```
$("span").attr("disabled", true);
```

The event handler continues to be called when I click on the span element.

I am testing in Chrome 13. Any thoughts?

Comment: It should be noted that it is semantically inappropriate to use a `span` for events. "The HTML <span> element is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

More appropriate would be a `button` element which does accept the `disabled` attribute appropriately.

Answer (score 97):

Try this:

```
$("span").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

you can enabled those back by

```
$("span").css("pointer-events", "auto");
```

Comment: This is the only solution I could get to work for me! Thanks!

Comment: This answer could be extended to work globally by simply using css: `span[disabled] { pointer-events: none; }`. This way you don't need to worry about resetting pointer-events to auto.

Comment: Or you could use a class like `.clicks-disabled { pointer-events: none }`. Now you can easily add or remove this class whenever required rather than mixing CSS with your JS.

Comment: Unfortunately `pointer-events:none` disallows the ability to attribute a correct cursor for the user, `cursor: not-allowed` when creating the effect of a disabled button/submit.

Answer (score 12):

The `disabled` attribute is not global and is only allowed on form controls. What you *could* do is set a custom data attribute (perhaps `data-disabled`) and check for that attribute when you handle the click event.

Answer (score 10):

The disabled attribute's standard behavior only happens for form elements. Try unbinding the event:

```
$("span").unbind("click");
```

Comment: The `button` element also supports the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Does not work for hover event

Answer (score 8):

Try unbinding the event.

```
$("span").click(function(){
alert($(this).text());
    $("span").not($(this)).unbind('click');
});
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xYRMq)

Comment: Fiddle link is broken!

Comment: @user1012513 thanks for notifying, it seems like a SO bug. I have included the code in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a dirty trick, what I have used:

I am using bootstrap, so I just added `.disabled` class to the element which I want to disable. Bootstrap handles the rest of the things.

Suggestion are heartily welcome towards this.

**Adding class on run time:**

```
$('#element').addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: That worked for me. A slight change is I used .toggleClass to set and remove the attribute, which does just what I want.

Answer (score 1):

`@click=" canClick ? doClick : void 0"`

User click but nothing happen can meet your

I use it in vuejs work fine

Answer (score -2):

The best method is to wrap the span inside a button and disable the button

```js
$("#buttonD").click(function(){
  alert("button clicked");
})

$("#buttonS").click(function(){
  alert("span clicked");
})
```

```css
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled" id="buttonD">
    <span>Disabled button</span>
</button>

<br>
<br>

 <span class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled" id="buttonS">Disabled span</span>
```