# Which HTML tags can be used with onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, dom-events

Which HTML tags can have an `onclick` event and which cannot? If there are tags where I cannot include an `onclick` event I want to know why not?

```
onclick="func()"
```

Are there any rules that you should adhere to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All HTML elements can have an `onclick` attribute.

See [the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1) for confirmation.

(Of course, some elements are not rendered by default so you would have to alter their `display` properties with CSS before they can be clicked on to trigger the event handler).

Comment: to include an onClick in a html or title tag is nonsensical, but i can do this?

Comment: Yes you can do this, but it is not recommended as it is obtrusive.

Comment: It isn't nonsensical. The html element is rendered, so you could bind an event handler to it to trigger if any part of the document is clicked (quite useful if you want to generate heat maps of your page, although I'd tend to bind directly on the `window` object myself). It is rather odd to make a title clickable, but `head, title { display: block; }` in a stylesheet will make it possible.

Comment: @TylerH, so what elements are there for which this is recommended and non-obtrusive?

Comment: @Dan Most others below `<body>`, frankly.

Comment: @TylerH "below <body>"? Do you mean "most elements that can appear within the <body> tag, except for <div> and <span>", or elements that are listed somewhere in a list where "body" is in the middle of the list?

Comment: @Dan I mean the former.

Answer (score 3):

While it's possible to attach an `onclick` to practically anything, some elements have further support for being clicked (or, rather, preventing clicks) and other elements don't.

Compare [the comments on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657545/setting-attribute-disabled-on-a-span-element-does-not-prevent-click-events) and the resulting link to the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) which strongly imply that elements such as `<div>` and `<span>` should not be used for click-actions because they "do not inherently represent anything" and "It should be used only when no other semantic element is appropriate."