# click to show phonenumber on multiple hml files with multiple locations

Tags: javascript, html

I have 200 html files where I have to hide phone number until we click on a text, so I need to change all the files content using some tool like GrepWin.  I can do that with this code but the problem is that the function name and id needs to be changed for all locations within the same page that have the same content. So this line is present several times on the same file:

```
 <p>
   <b>Contact data: 
 <script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "0316 301 958";} . 
 </script>
 <button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Show the number</button>
 <p>
 <b>Contact data: 
 <script>
  function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "0316 301 958";} . 
 </script>
   <button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Show the number
   </button>
```

I need different solution to change them all on all html files but to show the number(which is the same for all). At this point is only showing one number http://jsfiddle.net/qyzkfush/ . I can manually edit the function name and button id but it will take me ages to change 200 files content with many positions in each file. I need to use GrepWin to search the code and replace it for all files.

Comment: You shouldn't have two elements with the same ID. ID's are suppose to be unique. Also wouldn't it be quicker to create a dynamic page and pull the contents in rather than having a separate page for each contact?

Comment: I know that but how to solve my problem, all I need is to show the same number (when click on text) on all html files where Contact data: is found.

Comment: I need to alter all pages as requested by the webpage owner.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to you can run the follow:-

```js
function myFunction(e, phoneNumber) {
  e.innerText = phoneNumber;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Contact data: 
<button id="demo" onclick="myFunction(this, '0316 301 958')">Show the number</button>

<p><b>Contact data:
<button id="demo" onclick="myFunction(this, '0316 301 957')">Show the number</button>
```

I would only use this as a quick fix, I would have a word with the client about making the content dynamic.

Comment: worth noting that using event handlers are much better practice than inline JS :)

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

1. Add the script only once per page.
2. Each element on the page must have a unique ID. You can't have several elements with the same ID.
3. You don't need a button to notice clicks. All HTML element support click handlers. Try `p` or `span` (see [Which HTML tags can be used with onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074841/which-html-tags-can-be-used-with-onclick))

Try this:

```
<p onclick="showPhoneNumber(this)">Click to see phone number.</p>
```

This will add an event listener to the `p` element which will call the function `showPhoneNumber` with the `p` element as parameter (`this` will contain the element that triggered the event when the browser evaluates the short script in the `onclick` parameter).

The function will then look like this:

```
<script> 
  function showPhoneNumber(elem) {
      elem.innerHtml = '0316 301 958';
      return false;
  }
</script>
```

This should also work but would make it trivial to scrape the phone number from the HTML source:

```
<p onlick="this.innerHtml = '0316 301 958'; return false;">Click to see phone number.</p>
```

and I believe that's the main reason to hide the number behind a click (= to stop scripts from finding it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the phonenumbers as class name:

```js
function myFunction(className) {
[...document.getElementsByClassName(className)].forEach(element => element.innerHTML = className);
}
```

```html
<p><b>Contact data: <button class="0316 301 958" onclick="myFunction(this.className)">Show the number</button>
     <p><b>Contact data: <button class="0316 301 958" onclick="myFunction(this.className)">Show the number</button>
          <p><b>Contact data: <button class="0754 520 952" onclick="myFunction(this.className)">Show the number</button>
               <p><b>Contact data: <button class="0316 301 958" onclick="myFunction(this.className)">Show the number</button>
```