# Which HTML elements do I use for a click event?

Tags: html, onclick

Recently, I came across this issue I was working on one of the projects and in the theme, it is using a click function on a `<span>` tag. It was working fine on all browsers except Safari. I did some research and found out a lot of people faced this kind of issue on Safari.

I resolved my issue using `role="button"` on `<span class="menuOpen" role="button">Menu</span>` based on the information found here:
[Click event on <span> or <div> tag not working safari issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70667742/click-event-on-span-or-div-tag-not-working-safari-issue/70679464)

But this problem made me wonder what elements we can use for "click" events.

As per my knowledge, we can add `click` events on almost all elements, but per the HTML standard, we should add click events only on `<a>` or `<button>` tags.

Are there any other HTML elements we should use to trigger a `click` event?

Comment: You can have an `onclick` event on any tag as per HTML5 specification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074841/which-html-tags-can-be-used-with-onclick

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue on Safari 15.2 on IPadOs15.2.1.  The `onclick` event is defined in [GlobalEventHandlers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#idl-definitions) mixin  and the [HTMLElement](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlelement) interface implements it. So technically all elements implementing `HTMLElement`  interface should support onclick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are (currently) a total of 5 HTML elements that can be used by default as a '*clickable*' element:

- Buttons (any type)
- Inputs type;

  - Button
  - Radio
  - Checkbox
  - Range
  - Reset
  - Submit
  - Image
- Labels
- Selects
- Anchors (though I would discourage this because of the intended behaviour)

You can find a reference of HTML Elements at [Mozilla Developer | HTML Elements Reference | Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element).

Technically you can make any element *clickable* by modifying the elements global `.onclick` attribute, Mozilla provides an example of this here [Mozilla Developer | GlobalEventHandlers.onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#examples). Though if you do this please ensure you also modify the elements *role* attribute to `role=button` (as was stated in **OP**s question), this allows assistive technologies to find the element. A list of ARIA attributes (including the button role) can be found at [Mozilla Developer | Using ARIA: Roles, states, and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques)

The W3Cs Web Content Accessibility Guidelines also outlines certain elements that should be used for keyboard interactions with Assistive Technologies [W3C | WCAG | Using HTML form controls and links](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H91.html), though for this question I believe any element under the roles:

- grouping
- editable text

can be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function Menu() {
  console.log('Show Menu');
  $('.menuBar').toggleClass('d-none');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<span Onclick="Menu()" class="menuOpen">Menu</span>
<ul class="d-none menuBar">
  <li>Action 1</li>
  <li>Action 2</li>
  <li>Action 3</li>
  <li>Action 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

just give your tag an atribute named onlcick and fill the function name in after that.
it doesnt realy mater what tag you use, you can use every tag as a clickable element on your webpage.
so no matter if its a `<a>` or a `<button>` a `<p>` or `<div>`

its just works with all tags in html

just do teh following to add click funcionallity to your tags

```
<span class="menuOpen" onclick="FunctionName">Menu</span>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp